# HighCharts series Z index

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to bring a series to front in Highcharts without reversing the order of the series?

In my code, I've used:

```
$('#graf-1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Highcharts has a [zIndex](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zIndex) property.

```
       series: [{
            name: eixoz,
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: dataz,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },
            zIndex: 2

        }, {
            name: eixoy,
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'column',
            data: datay,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' €'
            },
            zIndex: 1
        }]
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQ6Uk/).