# keep column in front of spline lines in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

is there some way to keep in front the bar column instead spline lines in a mix chart?
If you in the attached images spline lines are in the front. I would have the lines behind of the column. is that possible?

[image: spline line are in front of the rest of columns]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zIndex` property to define the order, see also [HighCharts series Z index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797089/highcharts-series-z-index) or so.